Data recovery from floppies with Norton utilities Disktools
I use Msdos 6.22 and Disktools from Norton Utilities to restore  old floppies.
And I could do it with some of these diskettes fully or partially. I work with Samsung Sfd321B floppy drive.
Now I want to khow, if it is worth to use other floppy drives for another diskettes.
The matter is. I run Msdos 6.22. and then Norton Utilities Disktools, select Diskette revival.
The diskette is restored. I work with real computer in Ms dos 6.2.2 and have partial success, because 3 of 8 floppies were restored. One was restored in part.
When I write restored I mean the following. Boot record become readable, file allocation table errors were corrected.  Media description errors were corrected on some floppies
All restored discs passed every Norton diagnose test. They have bad sectors, but as a whole they are read.
Before working with Norton Utilities I tried to read the floppy disks in Windows Xp, Windows 10, in virtual machine with Windows 98, some ancient and new versions of Linux. No success with 5 internal and external floppy drives. Floppies were not recognized or were stated as unformatted.
Calling to special service firm is unreal.
So please inform, if it is worth to run Disktools diskette revival on the other floppy drives for data restore.
.

Have you try to get different media. Floppies are quire unreliable...

Also you can check here: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

I want to revive and then to recover data.
